# A strange norm in the polynomial space $\mathbb{P}[0,1]$. A contradiction?

Tags: functional-analysis, fake-proofs

Let us define a norm $\|f\|=\sup_{k\geq 0}\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|f^{(k)}(t)|$. It is easy to see that in the polynomial space $\mathbb{P}[0,1]$ space, the norm $\|\|$ is well-defined.

**What is the dimension of the completion of $(\mathbb{P}[0,1],\|\|)$ under this norm ?**

It seems to be finite dimensional, because one can show that the unit ball in this new Banach space $X$ is compact as follows:

We only need to show that every bounded sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $X$ has a convergent subsequence. That is a repeated application of the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem and Cantor's diagonal argument; the boundedness of $\{f^{(k+1)}_n\}$ implies the equicontinuity of $\{ f^{(k)}_n\}$. For details of this argument, we can refer to

[Is there no norm in $C^\infty ([a,b])$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918318/is-there-no-norm-in-c-infty-a-b)

Since it is a normed space with Montel-Heine-Borel property, it has to be finite dimensional.

On the other hand,  $\mathbb{P}[0,1]$ is already infinite dimensional. Then $X$ has to be at least infinite dimensional.

**Something must be wrong.**

references:

[Every normed space has a completion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768107/every-normed-space-has-a-completion)

Comment: By Ascoli-Arzelà theorem, one can show that any bounded sequence in such space has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Why must a space with the "Montel-Heine-Borel property" be finite-dimensional ?

Comment: Because in such normed space, the unit ball is compact.

Comment: Convergence in this norm does not only mean that all derivatives converge uniformly, but also that they must all converge "uniformly fast". The map $p \mapsto (p, p', p'', \dotsc)$ is an isometric embedding of $(\mathbb{P}[0,1], \lVert\cdot\rVert)$ into $\ell^{\infty}\bigl(\mathbb{N}, C([0,1])\bigr)$. So the completion is the closure of its image in $\ell^{\infty}\bigl(\mathbb{N}, C([0,1])\bigr)$, which is $$\bigl\{ F \in c_0\bigl(\mathbb{N}, C([0,1])\bigr) : (\forall n)(F_{n+1} = F_n')\bigr\}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the unit ball in $X$ is not compact. The Ascoli-Arzelà theorem and Cantor's diagonal argument are not strong enough to yields the convergent subsequence in $X$. Indeed, let us consider $f_n=\frac{x^n}{n!}$. On can show that $\|f_n\|=1$, and $\|f_n-f_m\|=1$ if $n\neq m$.  Therefore, it does not have any convergent subsequence. However, one can find that for any $k$,  it holds that 
$\|f_n\|_{C^k[0,1]}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.